# Inserting system date in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to insert system date in dd/mm/yyyy to table using oracle 10g?

While using the following query, it inserts system date as 03/04/0013. I need 03/04/2013. Can you help me to solve this problem?

```
insert into GtTable 
values('111','Name',300,'Tour',to_date('02/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

But when inserting '02/04/2012' directly, it accepts as same as '02/04/2012'.

Comment: Are you sure it is working? Have you tried something like  `'22/04/2012'`? What is `nls_date_format` set?

Answer (score 16):

You shouldn't activate `TO_DATE` on a date

`sysdate` is already a date, when you run `TO_DATE` with it as the first parameter, you make Oracle implicitly convert it to a string according to `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which in your case probably contains `YY` and not `YYYY`.

A date in oracle is a number representing a date and time, it doesn't have a "format", if you want to insert sysdate without the time value you need to truncate it like this:

```
insert into GtTable 
values('111','Name',300,'Tour',to_date('02/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'),trunc(sysdate))
```

Answer (score 6):

If the last field on your insert is a date type field, you should not need any conversion on SYSDATE, so, the following should be OK:

```
insert into GtTable 
values('111', 'Name', 300, 'Tour', to_date('02/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), sysdate);
```

But if it is a varchar field, the following should work:

```
insert into GtTable 
values('111', 'Name', 300, 'Tour', to_date('02/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Comment: I try to use it to insert current date but it gives me date format not recognized error to_date(SYSDATE,'DD-MMM-YYYY')

Comment: @MRAND I think the problem you're getting was covered by **A.B.Cade** above, in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15779452/2156229)

Answer (score 1):

I think the format of  displaying is due to the environment parameter。
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') CAN LET YOU inserts system date as DD/MM/YYYY ,but, it is not date type anymore.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, since if the data type is a `DATE` then oracle will implicitly convert the string to a date according to nls_date_format and even though the `to_char` function will work correctly, the insert will fail... see [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9430)

Comment: Year,you are right. If just want to display as dd/mm/yyyy ,to_char can work. While just for inserting,if this column is data type ,the insert will fail.You can to_date back,but this is a little stupid...   :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is the following

```
insert into method (id,name,created_by,updated_by, created_at, updated_at) values (1,'GET',0,0,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss'),null);
```

Comment: what is the column datatype in oracle and Java for such type of date format ? to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss') ?